# TypeError: string indices must be integers - JSON Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-requests

So I'm, getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/db/dm testing.py", line 12, in <module>
   for id in ids['id']:
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

With the following code:

```
import requests
import json

token = 'mytoken'

headers = {
    'Authorization': token,
}

r = requests.get('https://canary.discordapp.com/api/v6/users/@me/channels', headers=headers).json()
ids=json.dumps(r)
for id in ids['id']:
    print(id)
```

The JSON looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": "771634716042461195", 
  },
  {
    "id": "771654126345781278", 
  }, 
  {
    "id": "771658044526034967", 
  }
]
```

I want to print out the channel id's, which in this case are:
771634716042461195 and 771654126345781278.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: `dumps` turns objects into strings. Did you mean to use `json.loads` to turn a JSON string into a list/dict…?! Or, just, nothing, since you already decode the JSON with `.json()`?

Comment: `for i in r: print(i['id'])`…?

Answer (score 0):

You are converting your parsed json back into a string, but you want it to be a dictionary, not a string. You can completely remove the second line.

```
r = requests.get('https://canary.discordapp.com/api/v6/users/@me/channels', headers=headers).json()
for id in r['id']:
    print(id)
```

Comment: I'm trying to get the IDs of the channel from the dictionary, not the whole dictionary - although what you have suggested does work, it is not what I am after.

Comment: i think it mean failed while to get "ids['id']" or ids['id'] is empty/None, please check your token again and make sure requests get status_code

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I found the solution, here is my final code:

```
import requests
import json

token = 'mytoken'

headers = {
    'Authorization': token,
}

r = requests.get('https://canary.discordapp.com/api/v6/users/@me/channels', headers=headers).json()
x = 0

for i in range(len(r)):
    print(r[x]['id'])
    x+=1
```

It prints all the ID's of the channels. Hopefully this can help some other people out.